How can I decode the data for an event emitted by an inner instruction?
For this transaction for example - how can I decode the data in the buy function? I have the IDL. I've tried creating a struct and converting the data to an Uint8 Array and then decoding but I'm getting the wrong values.
const TradeEvent = struct([
 publicKey('mint'),
 u64('solAmount'),
 u64('tokenAmount'),
 bool('isBuy'),
 publicKey('user'),
 i64('timestamp'),
 u64('virtualSolReserves'),
 u64('virtualTokenReserves')
]);
const eventData = TradeEvent.decode(bs58.decode(data));

This what the event looks like in the IDL:
{
  "name": "TradeEvent",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "mint",
      "type": "publicKey",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "solAmount",
      "type": "u64",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "tokenAmount",
      "type": "u64",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "isBuy",
      "type": "bool",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "user",
      "type": "publicKey",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "timestamp",
      "type": "i64",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "virtualSolReserves",
      "type": "u64",
      "index": false
    },
    {
      "name": "virtualTokenReserves",
      "type": "u64",
      "index": false
    }
  ]
},

And this is the data 2K7nL28PxCW8ejnyCeuMpbXZUfeDyrPoM2H4ATLtBB7EJELFhXfRJTeoZUoP8tc4gz9aB1HCv8qjQsuHxzmbMsvzrYD57bxyxnDssm5BnfsmuCU7zEhRf5aNboey8GAiohYxjqMeCu6nA6MXSbFi8GZ3reZGpDYNCfSMAxDb5xJB8tmTXRxMNX5MVY3H

Could you share the code?
Not sure because bs58.decode(data) returns unit8Array, not buffer.
